# How can we show that the sum of measurable functions over a countable index set is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $I$ be a countable nonempty set
- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $X_i:\Omega\to E$ be $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(E))$-measurable

If $(X_i(\omega))_{i\in I}$ is *summable*, i.e. $\exists X(\omega)\in E$ with $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists J\subseteq I,|J|\in\mathbb N:\forall K\subseteq I,|K|\in\mathbb N,J\subseteq K:\left\|X(\omega)-\sum_{k\in K}X_k(\omega)\right\|_E<\varepsilon\tag1\;,$$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, are we able to show that $X$ is $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(E))$-measurable?

This is clearly true, if $I=\mathbb N$, since in that case $X$ is the limit of a sequence of $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(E))$-measurable functions. How can we proceed in the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the limit of a sequence is measurable you're done.

The notion of summabililty you give is certainly invariant under bijections of $I$, so you can assume that $I=\mathbb N$. It's easy to see that if $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=s$ in that sense, then $s$ is the limit of the partial sums.

(Given $\epsilon>0$ choose a finite set $J$ as in the definition. Choose $N$ so $J\subset \{1,2\dots,N\}$. Now if $n>N$ let $K=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and note $J\subset K$...)

**Exercise** If $x_j\in\mathbb R$ then $\sum_{j\in\mathbb N}x_j$ is summable in the sense above if and only if it is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I've confused myself. First of all, I've considered an arbitrary nonempty set $I$. In that scenario, the claim doesn't hold and that's why I've added the countability assumption. I've simply forgotten for a moment that by the very definition of countability there is an injection $I\to\mathbb N$. Now, everything is easy as you've pointed out.